# CakePhp Paginator and Query String

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP version 2.4.2

I am using the Paginator component and there are cases where I also pass in a query string to filter the results even further.  The request looks like:

```
/widgets/index/page:2?category_id=8
```

This produces "requested address is not found".

How can I get pagination and a query string to work together?

Comment: What do your logs say? And do you have any (custom) routes that apply for this request? I have Pagination and querystrings that just look like your example URL that work just fine.

Comment: Don't mix named params and query strings. That will result in a mess. Try to use the new query strings only. Named params are a faulty implementation of it and are pretty much deprecated. They will be removed in future versions anyway (>= 3.0).

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of the named parameters and now my request looks like: /widgets?page=2&category_id=8 which is still producing a requested address not found error. If I remove &category_id=8 I get page 2 results and if I remove page=2& I can get the category results, but I am unable to filter with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being right in the documentation -- a try/catch block for out or range requests: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#out-of-range-page-requests  I get the previous page and redirect to that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is going on.  I'm hitting this condition in the Paginator Component:

```
        if ($requestedPage > $page) { 
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
```

With the additional filters I don't have enough results to warrant a page 2, thus the exception is thrown.  I'm unsure of how to solve it.  If an user is on page 2, 3, etc of results and selects another filter, I need to throw away the pagination if the filtered results are under my limit.

Answer (score 0):

This error is when $requestedPage  is greater than  $page i means  url request that page which not exit.

http://myweb.songzog.com/my-blog/details/882/how-can-i-get-pagination-and-a-query-string-to-work-together.html